# Hiding Recipients in a qbo3 Message/Search panel

Tags: behavior, qbo3

When using qbo3's Message/Search panel in a landing page to announce system changes to all users, every user that has acknowledged the message is appearing underneath the message, like this:

[image]

How can I disable the rendering of recipients, as this list will get very long?

Answer (score 0):

When rendering a `Message/Search` panel, you may specify which behaviors you want displayed. In this case, the key is to **omit** the **Recipient** behaviors, such as:

```
Message/Search?Behaviors=Selectable ParentLabel Labels TabLauncher MessageAttachments Unread
```

For a report landing page, this API call is typically defined in the  Search Panel field:

[image]

A quick recap of the behaviors listed here:

| Behavior | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Selectable | Enable multi-selection of rows by clicking on a row, and then shift-clicking on a later row to select all rows between the two selected. |
| ParentLabel | If a Message is bound to a parent object, execute an API call to get the friendly label of the parent object. |
| Lables | Enable display of any labels each Message is tagged with. |
| TabLauncher | Enable popping out of the `Message/Summary` into a panel to the right of the `Message/Search` panel. |
| MessgeAttachments | Display a link to any attachments associated with each messages. |
| Unread | Marks any unread message with a css style (defaults to `messageunread`). |